# Better way of rewriting below method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, optimization, c#-7.3

I have below method that does work Okay but I believe we can make it better by some how getting rid of these if conditions, but not sure how?

```
 protected void SaveSession<T>(T sessionProperty, Management management) where T : class
        {
            string propertyType = typeof(T).Name;

            if (propertyType.Equals(typeof(A).Name))
            {
                management.A = sessionProperty as A;
            }
            else if (propertyType.Equals(typeof(B).Name))
            {
                management.B = sessionProperty as B;
            }
            else if (propertyType.Equals(typeof(C).Name))
            {
                management.C = sessionProperty as C;
            }

            Session["mysession"] = management;
        }
```

I am using latest C# version 7.0

Comment: Which C# version are you using? In C# 7 and later you can use a pattern matching `switch` statement

Comment: I am using latest C# version

Comment: Get an ArrayList property in Management. Filter with Enumerable.OfType() and add/set the sessionProperty variable.

Comment: Sounds like a good place for the strategy pattern. Other than that, don't compare type names, just compare the types directly.

Comment: @User the latest released version is 7.3. The latest *preview* version is 8.0. I assume you use C# 7.3, or at least C# 7?

Comment: @Alejandro I am not been able to because one i type while other is class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# 7 and later you can use a pattern matching switch statement, eg :

```
switch(sessionProperty)
{
    case A a:
        management.A=a;
        break;
    case B b:
        management.B=b;
        break;
    case C c:
        management.C=c;
        break;
}
```

In earlier versions you can use the `is` operator to check the type, eg :

```
if (sessionProperty is A)
{
    management.A=(A)sessionProperty;
}
else if (sessionProperty is B)
{
    management.B=(B)sessionProperty;
}
```

Comment: sorry I am using I am using latest C# version 7.0

Comment: If `Management` could be changed, I would suggest an `ArrayList` property in it + `.OfType<T>()`

Comment: @User pattern matching works in C# 7

Comment: @bradbury9 why do that?

Comment: To reduce the amount of properties in Management. Seems like a poor design

Comment: @bradbury9 there's nothing wrong with using only the properties you need, with the types you need. That's how all classes work. A weakly typed list of values on the other hand can cause a lot of problems. Besides, that's what `dynamic` and ExpandoObject are for

Comment: @bradbury9 using a list of weakly typed values means that someone down the line will have to write the same kind of code the OP wrote to try and *read* the values.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos nah, just `T GetData<T>( return management.OfType<T>().SingleOrDefault(); )`. It would be problematic if there were multiple properties of the same type indeed, but it depends on the use case. If properties were needed, you answer would be sweet.

Comment: @bradbury9 think what that code does for a moment. It enumerates a list, type checks, then returns the first item. Compare that to `Management.A`, possibly a *domain* entity, with properties that clearly show what it's for. On the one hand, an opaque list of values that requires iterations and assumptions on what each value does. On the other hand, a direct reference that costs nothing and clean code that's easy to read. That's the difference between dynamically and statically typed languages, only in the case of the list of values you don't even know what's in there